# Applying normalization to RGB images and getting RGB images as output

Tags: computer-vision, rgb, vision

My question is very short and very naïve but I found very different answers on Internet. What is the most effective (and actually used in the Computer Vision community) way of normalizing an RGB image.
This question comes from the fact that algorithm like PCA or even contrast normalization are described often in their 2D-versions.
Therefore for whitening/global contrast normalization or whatever methods you like to preprocess images to feed to a statistical method of your liking: do you consider each channel separately or do you reshape the depth-3 thing into a rectangular 2D-array (of depth-1) (and how to do that while preserving structure) do your thing and then split it back to its former shape ?

I think each method has its advantages considering the image as a whole seems more meaningful but applying to each channel separately is more simple.

Comment: your question is too broad! Be specific about the question! Do you want to apply some filters and recover the original image from that processed image?

Comment: I will edit my question to make it more to the point as it confuses people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make my answer specific to ZCA whitening but I guess it is the same for others:
As the input of the PCA has the shape of a 2D-matrix with (nsamplesxfeatures) dimension. I thought of using the RGB channels as nsamples and the image in those channel flattened as features.
The answer seems to be to use nsamples as nsamples (the numbers of images you have if you have several RGB images) and to use the RGB-image completely flattened as features.
This answer leads me to believe that if you want to normalise an image you should use the general mean of the image and general standard deviation and not to consider each channel separately.
If somebody disagrees he is free to comment, I agree that my question was a bit too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to your question.

For most tasks it is sufficient to operate on separate RGB or HSI channels. Most images in image processing are gray scale anyway so most algorithms expect gray scale input.
In most scenarios pre-processing serves the sole purpose of reducing information to the necessary minimum. So an RGB output "back in its former shape" with preserved structures does not exist. At least in my world.
If you want RGB output from RGB input you would implement a function that operates on RGB values. Unless you can reduce the calculations to grayscale and already have the necessary grayscale functions implemented.
How can you reshape an image into a 2D array? Usually an image is a 2D array...

Comment: My question comes from the fact that most algorithm accept only grayscale input however in the case where I want the output image to be RGB too I need to adapt the algorithms to my need. By reshaping an image into a 2D-array I meant to flatten a depth3 image into a rectangular image of depth 1 not to lose any information from the colour that may be induced by a grayscale transformation but I do not know how things are being done that is why I asked the question,
I can narrow my question to any kind of normalization applied to an RGB that would lead to an RGB for instance whitening.

Comment: The answer in ML litterature seem to be to consider the image as a whole (even to the point of completely flattening it to perform whitening)